# how to implement MD5 hashing of a string in freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker, smooks

I am working on freemarker template using Smooks for EDI Translations

I just perform the MD5 hashing of a string in 16 digit hexadecimal format..

I am not able to find the relevant syntax for implementing Md5 hashing in Freemarker logic

when trying to import

```
#import java.security.MessageDigest
```

in freemarker in smooks-config.xml file, it throws an error

> Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "java.security.MessageDigest"

Comment: I am not aware of `freemaker` or `smooks` but if its a template engine cant you pass it params? Basically calculate the MD5 hash in java and then pass it as a paramter

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker templates can only `#import` other FreeMarker templates (see the [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_import.html#ref.directive.import)). Also, generally, you aren't supposed to calculate such things in FreeMarker templates. You should pass the already calculated hex string to the template.

But, if you can't do the above, then you can write a small utility object in Java that has the required methods, and then add that to the FreeMarker data-model, or to the FreeMarker configuration as "shared variable". However, I don't know if Smooks is configurable enough to do that.

If Smooks doesn't let you configure FreeMarker much (as needed above), you can write a `TemplateMethodModel` implementation in Java that calculates the value you need, and then create an instance of that inside your template as `<#assign md5 = 'com.example.MyMD5Method'?new()>`, and then later you can do things like `${md5(something)}` in FreeMarker. (Of course, this requires that you can add a new class to your application.)

Comment: Do you have any example for TemplateMethodModel for java implementation in freemarker...Because i tried assign directive it didnt worked out..I run through smooks.jar by executing freemarker template...

Comment: What's the error message? (Otherwise Google for `"implements TemplateMethodModel"`...)

Answer (score 0):

If the Md5 hashing can be performed by a static method of a given class and you really cannot do the job *before* the template is processed... you can *expose* this class to the template.

I'm not familiar with Smooks, but basically you need tell Smooks to inject a modified `FreemarkerManager` which has an overriden method `populateContext`

```
public class MyFreemarkerManager extends FreemarkerManager {
    @Override
    protected void populateContext(ScopesHashModel model, ValueStack stack, Object action, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        super.populateContext(model, stack, action, request, response);
        BeansWrapper beansWrapper = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_24).build();
        TemplateHashModel staticModels = beansWrapper.getStaticModels();
        TemplateHashModel utils = (TemplateHashModel)staticModels.get("path.to.your.class.Utils");
        model.put("Utils", utils);
    }
}
```

Now all your templates have a direct access to the static methods of the `Utils` class

```
${Utils.hashMd5(s)}
```